# Add class to current nav item

Tags: javascript, pug, harp

I have simple question about adding a class to the current menu item.

I have the following page structure:

```
- index.jade
- about.jade
- articles/
  - _data.json
  - index.jade
  - blog-post-1.jade
  - blog-post-2.jade
- contact.jade
```

Now I created a class called: `.active` and it only works on the root pages (*index*, *about* and *contact*) but when I click on **`/articles`** the active class is not being added to the articles *`li`* in the menu.

I am using this code snippet from the Harp site:

```
ul
  li(class="#{ current.source == 'index' ? 'active' : '' }")
    a(href="/") Home
  li(class="#{ current.source == 'about' ? 'active' : '' }")
    a(href="/about") About
  li(class="#{ current.source == 'articles' ? 'active' : '' }")
    a(href="/articles") Articles
  li(class="#{ current.source == 'contact' ? 'active' : '' }")
    a(href="/contact") Contact
```

No matter what I try I can't seem to get the `.active` menu class to work on **`/articles`** nor any of the article pages: **`articles/blog-post-1`** or **`articles/blog-post-2`** and so on.

Also on the Harp site I saw you can add:

```
{
  path: ["articles", "hello-world"],
  source: "hello-world"
}
```

But I am not sure where to add it. I added it to the `articles/_data.json` file but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

So you don’t actually have to *add* the current source and the current path, that’s one of the things Harp makes available in your templates. You can just show it on the page anytime like this:

```
pre: code= JSON.stringify(current, 0, 2)
```

Say you are on the first blog post page, you’ll get something like:

```
{
  source: "blog-post-1"
  path: [
    "articles",
    "blog-post-1"
  ]
}
```

So in this case, your nav isn’t being activated because the `current.source` isn’t actually `articles`, it’s `blog-post-1` or `blog-post-2`. The quickest way to fix the problem would be:

```
li(class="#{ current.path[0] === 'articles' ? 'active' : '' }")
  a(href="/articles") Articles
```

This should still work for the articles index page as well, where Harp’s [`current` object](http://harpjs.com/docs/development/current) will look like:

```
{
  source: "index"
  path: [
    "articles",
    "index"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Kenneth but I still can't get the class of .active to be added to the posts in /articles?! When I click on /articles the class is active but when I click on "blog-post-1" the class does not get passes?!

Comment: Try logging out the data so you can see what metadata is actually present on that page to see if it is matching your expectations:

```
pre: code= JSON.stringify(current, 0, 2)
```

Comment: At the end I used: #{ current.source=='blog-post-2'?'active':'' }